# sql query to group data by conversation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with this task: 
I have a table in a MsSql database where I store inter users messages. I need a query to select the last message for each of the user conversation (WhatApp like list of conversations for a user).

Table structure (**x is the message ID, GUID, and is unique for each message, txtMsg is the text message**):

```
| messageId | fromUserId | toUserId | Message |     sentDate     |
|     x     |      1     |     2    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:00 |
|     x     |      1     |     2    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:01 |
|     x     |      1     |     2    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:02 |
|     x     |      2     |     1    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:03 |
|     x     |      3     |     1    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:04 |
|     x     |      4     |     1    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:05 |
|     x     |      2     |     3    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:06 |
|     x     |      2     |     4    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:07 |
|     x     |      2     |     3    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:08 |
|     x     |      1     |     5    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:09 |
|     x     |      3     |     1    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:10 |
|     x     |      2     |     4    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:11 |
|     x     |      2     |     5    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:12 |
|     x     |      1     |     2    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:13 |
```

Expected result example, for user with id = 1 (the sentDate is the newest date):

```
|     x     |      1     |     2    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:13 |
|     x     |      3     |     1    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:10 |
|     x     |      4     |     1    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:05 |
|     x     |      1     |     5    |  txtMsg | 1.1.2016 1:00:09 |
```

What sql query will create such result?

Thank you!

Later edit:
I added sqlfiddle example here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ffbe/15

Comment: The idea here is to set IDs for `from` and `to` in a fixed order.  You can do it, for example, with `CASE WHEN ... END` construct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `row_nubmer` with case logic to get the smallest and largest user ids:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by  (case when fromuserid < touserid then fromuserid else touserid end),
                                              (case when fromuserid < touserid then touserid else fromuserid end)
                                order by sentDate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from messages m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

This SQL works on the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fad5a/2):

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by  (case when fromuser < touser then fromuser else touser end),
                                              (case when fromuser < touser then touser else fromuser end)
                                order by createdAt desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from messages m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I cannot make your code run. Can you, please, put the query on my sqlfiddle table?

Comment: Works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM MessageData
WHERE messageID in
  (SELECT messageID FROM
    SELECT Max(sentDate), Max(messageID) messageID FROM
      MessageData m1 
       INNER JOIN
      MessageData m2
       ON
        m1.fromUserId = m2.toUserId
       OR
        m2.fromUserId = m1.toUserId
    GROUP BY sentDate, MessageID
  )
```

?

Comment: In my case the Id is GUID - [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL

Comment: So I cannot use the Max  function. Also, your code has an Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to your tables, nor your SQL engine of choice, probably.

Comment: Can you, please, put the query on that sqlfiddle table? Thank you.

Comment: Tried, but all I get is an error with no explanation about the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as answer by Gordon Linoff. I just added a filter for user id = 1 (either `from` or `to`). And I put the query in your [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ffbe/17/15).

The `ROW_NUMBER` partitions all rows into conversations and then assigns sequential numbers to each row in the conversation starting from the latest (ordered by `createdAt`).

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        M.Id
        ,M.fromUser
        ,M.toUser
        ,M.message
        ,M.createdAt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                CASE WHEN M.fromUser < M.toUser THEN M.fromUser ELSE M.toUser END,
                CASE WHEN M.fromUser > M.toUser THEN M.fromUser ELSE M.toUser END
            ORDER BY M.createdAt DESC) AS rn
    FROM Messages AS M
    WHERE 
        M.fromUser = 1
        OR M.toUser = 1
)
SELECT
    CTE.Id
    ,CTE.fromUser
    ,CTE.toUser
    ,CTE.message
    ,CTE.createdAt
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY fromUser, toUser;
```